# Removing 2 directory and php from url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My current url is:

`http://example.org/dir1/dir2/profile.php?username=someone`

I want it to look like this:

`http://example.com/someone`

My `.htaccess` file is in public_html folder and it is completely empty.

Please, can you help me?

Comment: Tried to clean up text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this  :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ /dir1/dir2/profile.php?username=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

The conditions make sure you don't rewrite any existing file/directories on the server.